# How can I resize views inside a navigationcontroller inside a popover?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a popover that gives a list of options to the user, and when the user clicks it pushes another view onto the stack. This works fine for the first view, but once one of the larger views is opened, the popover window won't shrink down to size when the user backs out of the navigation workflow. I've tried calling sizeToFit on the child views and on the navigation view, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

How can I make sure the popover and navigation controller are the correct size for the current view being shown?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in this type of workflow, let's say you start with VC1.  From VC1, you present a popover to user with selection choices.  User makes a selection from the list (a tableview, etc.)  You then need to (from the popover) make a callback to VC1 and pass back along any data which in this case user's selection to VC1.  VC1 then dismisses the popover and then prepares another view controller with that data and push the new view controller on to the display/navigation stack.  That is a pattern I would use.

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying that if the user chooses UserPickedVC from SelectionVC, you dismiss the popover and push SelectionVC followed by UserPickedVC all in one function so you still have back button behavior, or do you get rid of the navigation controller entirely?

Comment: Is the SelectionVC not the same as the popover?  If so, once you dismissed the popover, you just push the UserPickedVC.